# Twisted: dual-stack tcp server?

Tags: twisted, ipv6

In Twisted Python, how do I create a tcp server that listens on dual-stack ipv4 + ipv6? `tcp:443` and `tcp6:443` only accept ipv4 and ipv6 connections respectively, and they can't both run at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that `tcp` was listening on the ipv4 interface `0.0.0.0`. Listen on `::0` to accept both ipv4 and ipv6 connections.

`server6 = serverFromString(reactor, r"tcp:interface=\:\:0:port=443")`

Note the Python raw string `r""` to avoid having to double up the backslashes `\\`